# App Engine Java 11 could not find or load main class on live server

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-platform

**tl;dr:** Why does this work locally but not when I deploy to my live App Engine project?

I'm trying to create a barebones servlet-based web app using the Java 11 version of App Engine. I'm updating a few projects from Java 8  to Java 11 following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/java-differences). I'm also using [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/runtime#application_startup) and [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java11/appengine-simple-jetty-main). My goal is to use Jetty to run a very simple web app that serves a single static HTML file and a single servlet file in App Engine.

My web app works fine when I run locally:

```
mvn clean install
mvn exec:java -Dexec.args="target/app-engine-hello-world-1.war"
```

When I run these commands, both my `index.html` and my servlet URL work fine.

But when I deploy to my live site:

```
mvn package appengine:deploy
```

...the command succeeds, but when I navigate to my live URL, I get this error for both the HTML file and the servlet URL: `"Error: Server Error. The server encountered an error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds."` If I look in the logs in the Cloud console, I see this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class io.happycoding.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.happycoding.Main
```

Something is off with my setup, but I don't see anything obviously wrong.

Here are the files in my project:

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>io.happycoding</groupId>
  <artifactId>app-engine-hello-world</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <!-- App Engine currently supports Java 11 -->
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
      <version>9.4.31.v20200723</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
      <version>9.4.31.v20200723</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
      <version>9.4.31.v20200723</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>9.4.31.v20200723</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>io.happycoding.Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <projectId>happy-coding-gcloud</projectId>
          <version>1</version>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**src/main/appengine/app.yaml**

```yaml
runtime: java11
entrypoint: 'java -cp "*" io.happycoding.Main app-engine-hello-world-1.war'
```

**src/main/java/io/happycoding/Main.java**

```java
package io.happycoding;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;
import io.happycoding.servlets.HelloWorldServlet;

/** Simple Jetty Main that can execute a WAR file when passed as an argument. */
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 1) {
      System.err.println("Usage: need a relative path to the war file to execute");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class", "org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StrErrLog");
    System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL", "INFO");

    Server server = new Server(8080);

    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setContextPath("/");
    webapp.setWar(args[0]);
    ClassList classlist = ClassList.setServerDefault(server);

    // Enable Annotation Scanning.
    classlist.addBefore(
        "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
        "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");

    server.setHandler(webapp);
    server.join();
  }
}
```

**src/main/webapp/index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Google Cloud Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Google Cloud Hello World</h1>
    <p>This is a sample HTML file. Click <a href="/hello">here</a> to see content served from a servlet.</p>
    <p>Learn more at <a href="https://happycoding.io">HappyCoding.io</a>.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**src/main/java/io/happycoding/servlets/HelloWorldServlet.java**

```java
package io.happycoding.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/hello")
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;");
    response.getOutputStream().println("<h1>Hello world!</h1>");
  }
}
```

I'm guessing something is off with how I'm setting the classpath of the live site, but I don't see anything obviously wrong.

With the `packaging` property in `pom.xml` set to `war`, I get a `.war` file with these contents:

```
index.html
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/maven/io.happycoding/app-engine-hello-world/pom.properties
META-INF/maven/io.happycoding/app-engine-hello-world/pom.xml
WEB-INF/classes/io/happycoding/Main.class
WEB-INF/classes/io/happycoding/servlets/HelloWorldServlet.class
WEB-INF/classes/lib/asm-7.3.1.jar
WEB-INF/classes/lib/asm-analysis-7.3.1.jar
WEB-INF/classes/lib/asm-commons-7.3.1.jar
WEB-INF/classes/lib/asm-tree-7.3.1.jar
WEB-INF/classes/lib/javax.annotation-api-1.3.jar
WEB-INF/classes/lib/javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar
WEB-INF/classes/lib/jetty-annotations-9.4.31.v20200723.jar
WEB-INF/classes/lib/jetty-http-9.4.31.v20200723.jar
WEB-INF/classes/lib/jetty-io-9.4.31.v20200723.jar
WEB-INF/classes/lib/jetty-jndi-9.4.31.v20200723.jar
WEB-INF/classes/lib/jetty-plus-9.4.31.v20200723.jar
WEB-INF/classes/lib/jetty-security-9.4.31.v20200723.jar
WEB-INF/classes/lib/jetty-server-9.4.31.v20200723.jar
WEB-INF/classes/lib/jetty-servlet-9.4.31.v20200723.jar
WEB-INF/classes/lib/jetty-util-9.4.31.v20200723.jar
WEB-INF/classes/lib/jetty-webapp-9.4.31.v20200723.jar
WEB-INF/classes/lib/jetty-xml-9.4.31.v20200723.jar
```

If I change the `packaging` property in `pom.xml` to `jar`, then I get a `.jar` file with these contents:

```
io/happycoding/Main.class
io/happycoding/servlets/HelloWorldServlet.class
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/maven/io.happycoding/app-engine-hello-world/pom.properties
META-INF/maven/io.happycoding/app-engine-hello-world/pom.xml
```

And I get this error in the logs for the live site instead:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class io.happycoding.Main 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler
```

That feels like progress, but then I also get 404 errors in my live server, so I feel pretty stuck.

**What do I need to change about my above setup to make it work both locally and on my live server?**

**Edit:** I can see the following files in the App Engine debugger:

[image: app engine files]

I tried adding this to my `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>
          ${project.build.directory}/appengine-staging
        </outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then I see these file in the App Engine debugger:

[image: app engine files]

But I still get the same error.

I believe that the problem is caused by my `Main` class being inside a `.war` file which has no effect on the classpath, which is why it can't be found.

**How do I package my project up so it works locally and on my live server?**

Comment: Did you try to [build a fat jar](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/java-deploy#build_and_deploy_an_uber_jar)?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I tried, but I get the same results for the `jar` packaging. I've edit my question to include more details about what's in the generated `.war` and `.jar` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are including the `Main` class in the war itself, and App Engine is unable to find it.

As you can see in the [GCP migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/java-differences), the `Main` class is defined in an external dependency named `simple-jetty-main`.

With the execution of the `maven-dependency-plugin` this dependency is copied to the `appengine-staging` directory, making it accessible from the Java classpath.

This is the reason why the `Main` class can be found in the example proposed in the guide when executing the command from the `app.yaml` `entrypoint`:

```yaml
entrypoint: 'java -cp "*" com.example.appengine.demo.jettymain.Main helloworld.war'
```

Therefore, the solution will be to include your `Main` class in another library, independent from the war file that you need to deploy.

Maybe you can create a library - as Google does with `simple-jetty-main` - that can reuse in your GCP projects for this task.

Just for testing, in order to confirm this point, you can use the `simple-jetty-main` library itself (you can clone the required code from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java11/appengine-simple-jetty-main). Install it, include the dependency in your `pom.xml`, include also the `maven-dependency-plugin`, and define your `entrypoint` as follows:

```yaml
entrypoint: 'java -cp "*" com.example.appengine.demo.jettymain.Main app-engine-hello-world-1.war'
```

For your comments, you will prefer not to have the separation between the `Main` class and the rest of the code.

To meet that requirement we must first change the `Main` class so that Jetty can serve `HelloWorldSevlet` and the static content. The code is actually very similar to the one you provided. Please excuse the simplicity of the setup, it is based on `web.xml` file; if necessary, further development can be done to deal with annotations or whatever is deemed appropriate:

```java
package io.happycoding;

import java.net.URL;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class Main {

  public static final String WEBAPP_RESOURCES_LOCATION = "META-INF/resources";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class", "org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StrErrLog");
    System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL", "INFO");

    Server server = new Server(8080);

    URL webAppDir = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(WEBAPP_RESOURCES_LOCATION);
    if (webAppDir == null) {
      throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Unable to find %s directory into the JAR file", WEBAPP_RESOURCES_LOCATION));
    }

    WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
    webAppContext.setContextPath("/");
    webAppContext.setDescriptor(WEBAPP_RESOURCES_LOCATION + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");
    webAppContext.setResourceBase(webAppDir.toURI().toString());
    webAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

    server.setHandler(webAppContext);

    server.start();

    server.join();
  }
}
```

The static resources can be loaded from a directory of your choice (it will be parameterized in the `pom.xml`).

For instance, I have created the `src/main/webapp` folder to store the static content.

In this folder, you also need to define - in this case, due to the way we setup Jetty - a `WEB-INF` directory with this `web.xml` file inside:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>io.happycoding.servlets.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

This is a `tree` of my source code setup:

[image: source code setup]

The `pom.xml` file is very similar to the one you provided. I only included the `maven-resources-plugin` to copy the web app static content to the jar file, and the `maven-shade-plugin` to generate an UberJar:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.happycoding</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-engine-hello-world</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- App Engine currently supports Java 11 -->
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <!-- Directory where static content resides -->
        <webapp.dir>./src/main/webapp</webapp.dir>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.31.v20200723</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.31.v20200723</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.31.v20200723</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.31.v20200723</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>io.happycoding.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-web-resources</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/META-INF/resources</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${webapp.dir}</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>io.happycoding.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
              <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
              <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.2.0</version>
              <configuration>
                <projectId>happy-coding-gcloud</projectId>
                <version>1</version>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

With this setup, you can run the application locally by executing the following command:

```sh
mvn exec:java
```

You can also run the program locally right from the java tool:

```sh
java -jar appengine-deploy-sample-1.jar
```

Sorry, I cannot test the setup in GCP but I think, that according to the migration guide, you can try to deploy the application without indicating the `entrypoint` in your `app.yaml`.

If it does not work, you can try to run the app by configuring an `entrypoint` similar to the following:

```yaml
entrypoint: 'java -jar appengine-deploy-sample-1.jar'
```

Or maybe:

```yaml
entrypoint: 'java -cp "*" -jar appengine-deploy-sample-1.jar'
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it helped me understand what was actually happening in the example code. My end goal is to create a simplified example to give students, so I'm going to try to figure out if I can eliminate the disconnect between the Main class and the rest of the code. There might be a way to do that with Jetty? Anyway, I want to leave this question open for now in case anybody has any ideas, but I'll likely accept your answer and award the bounty in a few days. Thanks again.

Comment: I understand Kevin. Yes, I think it is possible. Please, let me try. I will be back later.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I have updated the answer with a possible implementation in the way you indicated. Is that what you needed? I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks again José. I tried your recommendation, and it works locally, but I haven't figured out a way to upload the rest of the directory to App Engine (or make App Engine "see" inside the jar). [This](https://i.imgur.com/kgUjHi5.png) is what I see when I navigate to my live server. I need to figure out the best way to serve static content, either from the jar or by uploading the surrounding directory somehow. You've answered my original question though, so I'm going to accept and reward now. Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you very much @KevinWorkman. Regarding your question, the different web app resources (index.html, images, ...) will be uploaded into the jar itself. We have configured Jetty to read these static content from the classpath. To give you more freedom, I will update the answer so you can have a directory entirely devoted for web app contents. The contents of the app engine staging looks fine: did the application work on GCP?

Comment: I updated the answer as indicated in the previous comment. Please, be aware that there are changes in the source code folder structure, the ```Main``` class, and the ```pom.xml``` file. Please, let me know it I can help you in any way.

Comment: I am very happy to hear that Kevin! Please, if you need something else, feel free to contact me, I will be delighted to help you. Thank you!