# App Engine Java 11 Gradle - Unable to load main class in production

Tags: java, gradle, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently working on migrating a Java 8 App Engine project to Java 11 as [documented](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/java-differences) in the migration guide by Google. A lot of the examples and documentation focus around Maven and I have adapted what I can to Gradle and gotten most of the way there. However, I'm facing an issue of getting the deployed code to find the Main Class of the embedded Jetty Server packaged with the project.

I'm able to run the project locally inside of Visual Studio code via the inline 'run' tools which executes the following command:

```
C:\\Program\ Files\\Eclipse\ Adoptium\\jdk-11.0.18.10-hotspot\\bin\\java.exe -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:56132 @C:\\Users\\test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cp_dz6hms01lt5nflua2xbcqzqr4.argfile com.example.server.ServerMain
```

This matches what is documented in one of the [repackaging guides](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/war-packaging#gcloud-tooling) from Google as well when executing the war. The argfile referenced in the above command appears to just list all the libraries and dependencies used in the project.

`java -cp "*" com.example.appengine.demo.jettymain.Main helloworld.war`

All the endpoints work as expected and I'm even able to to deploy the code to App Engine without issue.

Very similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63333073/app-engine-java-11-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-on-live-server) once the code is deployed it cannot load the Main Class using the specified entry point. I realize this may sound like a duplicate question but moving from Maven to Gradle feels different enough to cause some serious headaches.

**App.yaml**

```
runtime: java11
entrypoint: 'java -cp "*" com.example.server.ServerMain server.war'
```

Looking over the answer in the above issue, the solution proposed was the modify the maven build script to package the project into a jar instead and modify the entrypoint to start the webserver as you would any other jar. However, using the App Engine Gradle plugin, a jar is not generated and the war task is executed instead. Furthermore, when I manually go to run the a shadowJar locally the webserver is never accessible for testing. So I believe this solution might not work for a Gradle based project.

I have attempted to force the war to include the required manifest information with the following in the build.gradle with no success. The expected manifest is generated but as it's a war it still doesn't appear to want to execute.

```
war {
  webInf { from 'src/main/appengine'}
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Main-Class': 'com.example.server.ServerMain'
    )
  }
}
```

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.example.server.ServerMain
```

I feel like some variation of the 'java -cp' entrypoint should work as I'm able to run something similar locally but I don't have a lot of experience with the java flags and not sure where to go from here.

**Additional Information**

I would use the appengine-simple-jetty-main external Jetty library as used [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/main/appengine-java11/helloworld-servlet). However, I'm running an embedded jetty server as I have a custom resource config which I don't think will apply correctly.

**ServerMain.java**

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jetty.JettyHttpContainerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class ServerMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            ResourceConfig config = new App();
            Server server = JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(URI.create("http://0.0.0.0:8080/"), config);

            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
                try  {
                    System.out.println("Shutting down the application...");
                    server.stop();
                    System.out.println("Done, exit.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ServerMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                }
            }));

            Thread.currentThread().join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**App.java**

```
@ApplicationPath("/*")
public class App extends ResourceConfig {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());

    public App() {
        packages("com.example.server.handlers",  "com.example.server.filters", "com.example.server.interceptors");
        register(GsonJerseyProvider.class);
        register(MultiPartFeature.class);

        Sentry.init(options -> {
            options.setDsn(System.getenv("SENTRY_URL"));
        });

        try {
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
                .setDatabaseUrl(System.getenv("FIREBASE_URL"))
                .build();

            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            log.severe(e.getMessage());
            Sentry.captureException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.severe(e.getMessage());
            Sentry.captureException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is, how do I package a Gradle project into a war/jar that can be executed both locally and deployed via the 'appengineDeploy' task that will work?